# Why are my folders and files set with group "\root"?

Tags: server, permissions, groups

One of our servers (14.04.5 LTS) was shutdown by a UPS managed event - the system logs indicate a pretty normal shutdown, and it restarted 30 minutes or so later.

Our first indication of a problem was that the mysqld service isn't starting (apache2 and sshd are). While investigating, I found that many folders and files are grouped to "\root":

```
drwxr-xr-x  22 root \root  4096 Sep 20 06:30 ./
drwxr-xr-x  22 root \root  4096 Sep 20 06:30 ../
drwxr-xr-x   2 root \root  4096 Aug  3 09:06 bin/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root \root  4096 Sep 20 08:48 boot/
drwxr-xr-x  14 root \root  4340 Sep 29 15:19 dev/
drwxr-xr-x 115 root \root  4096 Sep 29 15:17 etc/
drwxr-xr-x  11 root \root  4096 Sep 26 13:31 home/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root \root    33 Sep 20 06:30 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-96-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root \root    33 Aug 30 06:50 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-95-generic
drwxr-xr-x  22 root \root  4096 Aug 18 13:06 lib/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root \root  4096 Aug  1 10:27 lib64/
drwx------   2 root \root 16384 Aug  1 09:43 lost+found/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root \root  4096 Aug 18 13:19 media/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root \root  4096 Apr 11  2014 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x   5 root \root  4096 Aug  3 09:21 opt/
dr-xr-xr-x 143 root \root     0 Sep 29 15:17 proc/
drwx------   3 root \root  4096 Aug 18 13:00 root/
drwxr-xr-x  19 root \root   640 Sep 29 15:20 run/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root \root 12288 Sep 12 09:01 sbin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root \root  4096 Apr 17  2014 srv/
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root \root     0 Sep 29 15:17 sys/
drwxrwxrwt   5 root \root  4096 Sep 29 15:27 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  10 root \root  4096 Aug  1 09:44 usr/
drwxr-xr-x  17 root \root  4096 Aug 29 11:25 var/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root \root    30 Sep 20 06:30 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-96-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root \root    30 Aug 30 06:50 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-95-generic
```

Using `groups root` I get `root : \root` as the output.

Why has this happened?

How do I fix this?

I've tried restarting. All the searches on google I've tried for this just talk about `/root` directory.

Comment: What is the output of `groups root`?

Comment: @insert_name_here I have edited my answer with that result

Comment: That is very odd and suspicious. I would look in `/var/log/auth.log` for something like `group added to /etc/group: name=\root`

Comment: nothing in the auth logs going back for a month (logrotate seems to only keeps 4 weeks worth of the auth log) - it may be something our sysadmin did when he set the server up before that, I'll need to talk to him when we're both in the office again

Comment: Odd...what's the output of `grep root /etc/group` (with any sensitive usernames cut out, of course)?